# Как сделать функцию syscall?

Tags: c, linux, ассемблер, arm

Я хочу написать "Hello World" без glibc, для этого мне нужно написать свою маленькую libc, я сделал несколько простых функций которые не требуют системных вызовов, но теперь хочу сделать функцию write чтоб функция puts заработала, но для write нужна функция syscall, а для того чтоб сделать syscall нужно знать Асембрер, а я его совсем не знаю, я всеже рискнул попробовать написать hello world, после долгого гугления и через несколько десятков компиляций, я на экране увидел  "Hello World!", в первые пол секунды я не поверил что у меня вышло Гг

```
__asm__(
    ".data;"
    "msg:"
        ".ascii \"Hello, world!\n\";" // Строка для вывода
        "len = . - msg;" // Записуем в переменную len длину msg
);

void _start() {


    __asm__(
        "mov  r0, #1;" // Запись в поток #1 - stdout
        "ldr  r1, =msg;" // Указатель на строку
        "ldr  r2, =len;" // Длина строки
        "mov  r7, #4;" // Номер системного вызова - 4 (write)
        "swi  0;" // Системный вызов ядра
    );

    __asm__(
        "mov  r0, #0;"  // Возращаемое значение - 0
        "mov  r7, #1;" // Номер системного вызова - 1 (exit)
        "swi  0;" // Системный вызов ядра
    );
}
```

Насколько я понял для системного вызова нужно записать в переменную(или это ригистры, я не знаю чем отличается первое от второго) r7 номер вызова, а в переменные r1, r2, r3... передаваемые аргументы, но как написать функцию `syscall(номер вызова,Аргументы...)` я не знаю, тут нужно либо полностью писать её на Ассемблере, а это я точно не смогу, либо писать на C и передавать аргументы в Ассемблер, это я тоже не умею.

**Может кто либо помочь написать функцию syscall для arm?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот, накидал по-быстрому "Hello World", где системные вызовы осуществляются с помощью ряда функций `syscall<N>`, для различного количества аргументов `N`. Можно, конечно, заморочиться, и сделать еще единую функцию с переменным числом аргументов с помощью `va_list`.

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define SYS_EXIT  1
#define SYS_WRITE 4

#define STDIN  0
#define STDOUT 1
#define STDERR 2

size_t
strlen(const char *s)
{
    size_t n;
    for (n = 0; *s; ++n, ++s)
        ;
    return n;
}


void
syscall1(int cnum, int arg1)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "mov r0, %0;"
        "mov r7, %1;"
        "swi 0;"
        :
        : "r"(arg1), "r"(cnum)
        : "r0", "r7"
    );    
}

void
syscall3(int cnum, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "mov r0, %0;"
        "mov r1, %1;"
        "mov r2, %2;"
        "mov r7, %3;"
        "swi 0;"
        :
        : "r"(arg1), "r"(arg2), "r"(arg3), "r"(cnum)
        : "r0", "r1", "r2", "r7"
    );    
}


void
_start()
{
    char *msg = "Hello world\n";

    syscall3(SYS_WRITE, STDOUT, (int)msg, strlen(msg));
    syscall1(SYS_EXIT, 0);
}
```

Компиляция и запуск:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib test.c -o test
$ ./test
Hello World
```

Comment: То что нужно, а я гадал как передать переменные из C в Асемблер. Только зачем ты инклудишь stdint эсли комрилится с -nostdlib :D вставил #define size_t unsigned int и все заработало как надо.

Comment: `size_t` -- это обычный макрос из `stdint.h`, он обрабатывается препроцессором, `-nostdlib` на это не влияет, и все работает, если сами заголовочные файлы в наличии есть (у меня, разумеется, есть, и я не заморачивался, написал на скорую руку). А так, да, если хочется полностью отвязаться от стандартной библиотеки, то нужно определять самому.

Comment: Единственное что меня немного смущает это то что все преобразуется в int, Это не страшного?

Comment: @Виталий, не вижу проблемы, все параметры системных вызовов кладутся в регистры общего назначения, поэтому лишь бы размера `int` хватало (если архитектура у вас 64-разрядная, а `int` 32-разрядный, используйте `long`, чтобы помещались адреса; ну или вообще `intptr_t` из `stdint.h`, если не заморачиваться).

Answer (score 2):

пример [отсюда](http://labe.felk.cvut.cz/~stepan/33OSD/files/syscalls.pdf) для *intel*-архитектуры:

```
# hello.c
static inline long syscall1(long syscall, long arg1) {
  long ret;
  asm volatile ("int $0x80" : "=a" (ret) : "a" (syscall), "b" (arg1) : "memory");
  return ret;
}

static inline long syscall3(long syscall, long arg1, long arg2, long arg3) {
  long ret;
  asm volatile ("int $0x80" : "=a" (ret) : "a" (syscall), "b" (arg1), "c" (arg2),
  "d" (arg3) : "memory");
  return ret;
}

int write(int fd, const void *buf, int count) {
  return syscall3(4, fd, (long)buf, count);
}

void exit(int status) {
  syscall1(1, status);
}

void _start() {
  int retval;
  retval = write(1, "hello world\n", 12);
  exit(0);
}
```

компилируем:

```
$ gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -static hello.c -o hello
```

запускаем:

```
$ ./hello 
hello world
```

--

у архитектуры же *arm* другой ассемблер.

проверить не могу, т.к. *arm*-а под рукой нет, поэтому привожу пример [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21731154/4827341) как есть:

```
void _start() __attribute__ ((naked));
void _start() {
    main();
    asm volatile(
        "mov r7, #1\n" /* exit */
        "svc #0\n"
    );
}

int main() {
    linuxc('X');
    return 42;
}

void linuxc(int c) {
    asm volatile(
        "mov r0, #1\n" /* stdout */
        "mov r1, %[buf]\n" /* write buffer */
        "mov r2, #1\n" /* size */
        "mov r7, #4\n" /* write syscall */
        "svc #0\n"
        : /* output */ : [buf] "r" (&c) : "r0", "r1", "r2", "r7", "memory"
    );
}
```

компилировать, как я понимаю, надо с теми же параметрами (ну, разве что без указания битности — `-m32` — которая и в первом примере была необязательна).

Comment: К чему это? Мне не нужен hello world на Асемблере

Comment: вам же нужен системный вызов на ассемблере. // а! кажется, понял. вам требуется показать, как делается ассемблерная вставка внутрь функции в си-файле?

Comment: Мне нужна функция которая делает системный вызов как в glibc http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=syscall&category=2&russian=2

Comment: @Виталий, я привёл другой пример.

Comment: О, это то что нужно, только gcc ругается на -m32 и на "asm", заменил на `__asm__` перестало, но начяло писать такое: `error: impossible constraint in 'asm'__asm__ volatile ("int $0x80" : "=a" (ret) : "a" (syscall), "b" (arg1) : "memory");`

Comment: это уже связано, как я понимаю, с кросс-компиляцией. или это вы под *intel*-ом для *intel*-а собираете? тогда и *asm* и *-m32* не должны вызывать ошибок.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26898/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-).

Comment: Отписал в чате.